# If thread count is 1, is it sequential run or parallel run in karate

Tags: multithreading, karate

I am using karate 0.9.2 version and using parallel run code in runner, but giving thread count 1. now is this a sequential run or parallel? As I have defined only one thread?

```
Results results = Runner.parallel(getClass(), 1, karateOutputPath);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be sequential of course.